# Live preview the result of running a :substitute command in a :global command in neovim

Tags: neovim, highlight, previewing

Assuming the following text

```
foo
bar pattern needle
pattern needle
```

I can enter the following command `:g+pattern+s/needle/replacement` to replace all the needles in lines that contain `pattern`.

With neovim, before I press Enter, it highlights all the occurrences of `pattern`, but does not preview / temporarily replace the `needle`s.

```
foo
bar pattern needle
    _______  
pattern needle
_______
```

If I enter `:%s/needle/replacement`, before entering Enter, neovim *does* live preview which `needle`s will be replaced. It looks like this.

```
foo
bar pattern replacement
            -----------
pattern replacement
        -----------
```

Is it possible (are there any plugins) that allow highlighting the `:global` pattern and live-previewing the `:substitute`?

```
foo
bar pattern replacement
    _______ -----------
pattern replacement
_______ -----------
```

I found the following plugins, but neither seem to do both things.

https://github.com/markonm/traces.vim

https://github.com/chentoast/live.nvim